# Prove that there's no $x \in c_0$ such that $||x||_\infty = 1$ and $||T(x)||_\infty = ||T||$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:(c_0,||.||_\infty) \rightarrow (\ell^\infty,||.||_\infty)$
, $T(x)=(\frac{1}{3}x_1,\frac{2}{5}x_2,...,\frac{n}{2n+1}x_n,...)$

I calculated that $||T|| = \frac{1}{2}$. Now I need to prove that there's no $x \in c_0$ such that $||x||_\infty = 1$ and $||T(x)||_\infty = ||T||$ 
And I can't figure out how to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If a sequence $(c_n)$ tends to $0$  and $|c_n| <\frac 1 2$ for all $n$ then $\sup |c_n| <\frac 1  2$. Apply this to $c_n=\frac n {2n+1} x_n$.

[Note that there exists $N$ such that $|c_n| <\frac 1 2$ for all $n>N$. So the $\sup|c_n|$ will be attained at some integer $n$ between $1$ and $N$].

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that what you said isn't true. For ex $c_n = \frac{n}{2n+1}$ you have that $|c_n|< \frac{1}{2}$ for all n, but $sup |c_n|= \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Reborn67 Your $c_n$ does not tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: You're totally right. I can finish the excercise now. Thanks!!